# Sqlite trying to retrieve a row doesn't work IOS 9

Tags: objective-c

I'm saving an image in the document directory and then I save its path inside a `SQLite DB`. After the process finishes I try to retrieve the image path from the db but I can't get it working and I really have no Idea why. On the simulator the code works but on a real device it doesn't.
This is the code I've used to save the img path and to retrieve the img path and display the image inside an `UIImageView`

This is the code to save the image:

```
NSString *stringURL = @"http://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/user-media/addon_icons/80/80205-64.png?modified=1317416463";
    NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
    NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSString  *filePath;
    if ( urlData )
    {
        NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

        filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"test.png"];
        [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
    }

    NSLog(@"path:%@",filePath);
    [self saveImgPath:filePath];
```

This is the `saveImgPath` method:
-(void) saveImgPath:(NSString*)path{
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [databasePath UTF8String];

```
if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &ImgDB) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    NSString *insertSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"INSERT INTO ImgPath (path) VALUES (\"%@\")",path];


    const char *insert_stmt = [insertSQL UTF8String];

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(ImgDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        sqlite3_step(statement);

    }

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close(ImgDB);
}
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"sfondo" sender:self];
}
```

And this is how I retrieve it:

```
-(NSString*)getImgPath{

    NSString* imgPath;
    const char *dbpath = [[self GetDatabasePath] UTF8String];
    sqlite3_stmt    *statement;
    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &ImgDB) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSString *checkSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"SELECT * FROM ImgPath"];

        const char *insert_stmt = [checkSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(ImgDB, insert_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL);


            if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ERROR)
                NSAssert1(0,@"Errore  %s",sqlite3_errmsg(ImgDB));
            else
                sqlite3_step(statement);



        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(ImgDB);
    }
    return imgPath;
}
```

The DB is initialized correctly and the `NSLog` of the paths are correct but I get 0 results when I try to retrieve the image path

Comment: If you are saving the full path then your app will break when it's updated.  You need to save the path *relative* to the app's document folder.

Comment: @Droppy mm thanks thats a good info I didn't knew. What do you mean by relative path? Should I just save the image name?

Comment: Yes, and any intervening sub-folder(s), so that you can get complete path from the *current* document folder plus the path you saved.